# Informatica change all backslashs in shell commande source by forwardslashs

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a problem with the escape character. I used a command for a File Reader to generate source in a session and backslash \ for the escape character.

This is the script :

```
grep  '\['  /opt/informatica/fai/conf/DEV/*.prf
```

The script have been run without error in unix console. But when I ran the session, I encountered a problem. I have seen the session log, the session replaced all the backslash to forwardslash.

this is session log:

Error: [SQ_Shortcut_to_FichierParametrage_Session] Process id 1722. The shell command failed with exit code 2.

ERROR   28/08/2014 14:26:33 node_dev    READER_1_1_1    FR_3002 Error reading from file [**grep  '/['  /opt/informatica/fai/conf/DEV/*.prf**].  Operating system error message [No such file or directory].

ERROR   28/08/2014 14:26:33 node_dev    READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16034  ERROR: Fetch failed.

**The backslash have became the fowardslash.**

Comment: what is your "session" if not a unix console ?

Comment: The source is File Reader and I selected the input type as Command in the session configuration for this source. I used the the above script  as the Command.